# If $\frac1{t-s}\int_s^t f(r)\,\mathrm dr\le f(s)$ for all $0<s<t$, then $f$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function which verifies:
$$\frac1{t-s}\int_s^t f(r) dr\le f(s) \quad\forall\;s,t\;|\; 0<s<t<\infty$$ 
I have to prove $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Differentiability is not required as my answer below shows.

Comment: I think this is a good question in Calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$. By continuity $f$ has a minimum at some point $c$ in the interval. Suppose $c<b$. Then $\frac 1 {b-c} \int_c^{b} f(r)\, dr \leq f(c)$. This gives $\frac 1 {b-c} \int_c^{b} \{f(r)-f(c)\}\, dr \leq 0$ but $f(r)-f(c) \geq 0$ on $[c,b]$. Hence $f(r)=f(c)$ on $[c,b]$. In particular, $f(b)=f(c)$ so the minimum value of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is $f(b)$. Since this holds for every interval $[a,b]$ it follows that $f$ is decreasing.